# How do you redraw a canvas on top of another canvas or image every x seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, dom-events

Assume we have drawn an image on a canvas html div.

Now starting at `t=0`, I want to draw squares starting from `x,y=0,0` on top of this canvas with a space of `10px` between each square.

At `t=1`, I want to remove the old squares and redraw new squares that start at `x,y=1,1`

and so on

How do you do this automatically, at every `x` seconds? Perhaps put two canvas elements on each other, is that possible?

Comment: Are you asking for animation?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is something what you want, a moving square..

http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/ru8kthn6/

```
var pos=0;
var time=500;
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
setInterval(function(){
    ctx.beginPath();
ctx.clearRect(pos-2,pos-2,20,20);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.rect(pos,pos,10,10);
ctx.stroke();
pos++;

}, time);
```

You dont need to overlap two canvas elements for that, just remove and add another rectangle of increasing x,y positions would do.